# Firefox - Status bar URLs are being clipped

Tags: windows, firefox

I'm using Firefox(version 12) on Windows 7.

I have disabled trimming URLs via `about:config` setting:

```
browser.urlbar.trimURLs
```

i.e., the above key is set to `false`

If I close the browser, open it and go to a URL on a page, and point the mouse to it, it still shows it trimmed (i.e. when I move the mouse to the URL, but do not click yet, and look below the page, where the URL is displayed in the little box that comes up, the tooltip style box). I'd like to see the full URL in the tooltip box there.

I see  something like  `http:/abs.../file.htm` notice the dots in the name. It shortened it. Even though the URL is not large and can fit in the window, it still trims it by putting these dots.

What else can I do so that Firefox does not trim the URL?

Comment: `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` shows or hides the protocol (e.g. `http://`) in the address bar. It does not affect URLs in the status bar when you hover a link.

Comment: @iglvzx, ok thanks. Then how can I tell it to show full URL in the status bar when I hover the mouse over the link? I'd like to see the full URL before I click on it. I remember this used to work before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`browser.urlbar.trimURLs` shows or hides the protocol (e.g. `http://`) in the address bar. It does not affect URLs in the status bar. There is no preference in `about:config` to stop the status bar from clipping text, so we'll have to inspect the *Firefox Chrome* to see what's going on.

After some investigating, I see that the status bar is represented as an XUL `statuspanel` element and with the following CSS:

```
statuspanel {
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://browser/content/tabbrowser.xml#statuspanel");
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -3em;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

---

So, using the [Stylish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), we can define the following rule to stop the status bar from clipping the URL in *most* cases (i.e. when the URL is shorter than your window):

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

statuspanel
{
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, +1 for the idea. But the add-on I installed worked, and simple, I did not have to do anything. But will accept your solution but will wait few more days in case someone has something else to say. I think it is annoying that firefox decides on its own what users want to see and not see.

Comment: I took a look at the add-on you used, and I can confirm that is has the same behavior as my solution. Extra long URLs that are wider than the window are still clipped. So, now I will try to see if I can change that behavior, so the URL is never clipped. Maybe I can make it wrap when it gets too long... Hmm

Comment: I'm reluctant to recommend that add-on as a solution, because it is overkill. We only want to change one thing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just found a solution and it works.

I installed an add-on to firefox to show the full url.

the add-on is called status-4-evar and it worked very well. Now the full URL is displayed in the tooltip preview.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/