# Status bar URLs are being clipped in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, statusbar

Same as [this question](https://superuser.com/q/422033/5106), but regarding Chrome.

When I mouse over a long URL, it puts `...` at the end. I don't like that.

Is there a way to disable it? An extension, a hidden `about:config` page, or a `chrome.css` file I can edit?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to see the full link of a `href` attribute:

1. Hover over the link and **stay still for a second**.

   The ellipsis now gets replaced by the truncated part of the `href` attribute.
2. If you don't want to wait, you can use an **extension**. For example:

   [Status Bar (Chrome Web Store)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ojjdiklbbogaliiljdbpbkkkghendjja)

   > #### Status bar to display non-truncated links on mouseover.
   >
   > Simple extension that does what it says. Nothing fancy.
   >
   > Features
   >
   > - Displays complete link (href attribute) on mouseover.  No more truncation.
   > - Displays complete Page Title five seconds after moving mouse off a link.
   > - Single-click bar to hide it until you mouse over another link.
   > - Double-click bar to hide it until you reload the page.
   > - Customize the look and location via CSS.

   The only problem: Now you have two status bars. To change this, open

   ```
   chrome-extension://ojjdiklbbogaliiljdbpbkkkghendjja/options.html
   ```

   and click `Load Defaults`.

   - To maintain only the built-in status bar, make the following changes:

     ```
     height           0px
     ```

     Then, click `Save`.
   - Unfortunately, there's no way to disable or hide Chrome's built-in status bar altogether. However, you can make both status bars blend in with each other.

     To do this, make the following changes:

     ```
     right            
     left             0px
     height           18px
     padding          1px 10px 0px 3px
     font-size        12px
     color            #808080
     background-color #DFDFDF
     border-top       none
     border-left      none
     border-right     none
     ```

     Then, click `Save`.

Comment: Quite nice, except it leaves the normal status bar in tact (so I have 2). Anyway to disable that?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to disable or hide Chrome's built-in status bar altogether. However, you can make both status bars blend in with each other (more or less seamlessly). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Today (Chrome 84) even waiting 1 second or 10 seconds, the URL is still truncated to 114 chars...

Comment: The "Status Bar..." link is a 404

Answer (score -1):

The ViewThru extension for Chrome might give you what you need.  More  here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jkncfnbcgbclefkbknfdbngiegdppgdd

Comment: No...did you read the description? This works on links to sites like tinyurl.

Comment: That is link is a 404